# Start view animation from custom frame- Android

Tags: java, android, animation, android-studio, progress-bar

I have a custom `CircleProgressBar` that does a little animation. i want to make this animation starts on custom frame instead of frame 1. Is there a way of doing that? i tried to extend `Animation` class but it downs't seam to have a method for this.

Comment: Why not just reorder the frames of your animation?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an `Animation` you might want to try using a `ValueAnimator` or an `ObjectAnimator` instead.  Then, you can use this method:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html#setCurrentPlayTime(long)

As it says in the documentation, if you start the animator and then set the current play time to wherever you want it to be, it should give you the effect you're looking for.